# Is it bad to use "return" to escape from the main method?

Tags: return, break, system.exit

So this might be an exceptionally dumb question, but before you burn this post to smolders, please hear me out XD. Below I've written three basic classes, all of which accomplish the same thing, but through various means:

**Class A ( break ) -**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ClassA
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a sentence (/q to quit): ");
            String sentence = in.nextLine();

            if(sentence.equals("/q"))
                break;
            else
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Class B ( return ) -**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ClassB
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a sentence (/q to quit): ");
            String sentence = in.nextLine();

            if(sentence.equals("/q"))
                return;
            else
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Class C ( System.exit(0) ) -**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ClassC
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a sentence (/q to quit): ");
            String sentence = in.nextLine();

            if(sentence.equals("/q"))
                System.exit(0);
            else
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
        }
    }
}
```

While I prefer Classes A and C, is there anything wrong with B? More specifically, is it bad practice to use a `return` statement to exit from the `main` method of a program? If so, why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `return` is exactly the right thing to do, because it makes your `main` easier to test -- your test framework doesn't need to intercept exit attempts.